# Connecting to Shopify's API in a rails Background Job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth-2.0, shopify, delayed-job, shopify-app

I have a background job in a Ruby on Rails app for Shopify which has been running every night for over a year. Some time after upgrading to Shopify_app 8.3.1 and rails 5 (from 4), I run into periodic problems starting a session manually in that background job.

Obviously, since a job does not inherit from the Authenticated Controller, I have to start a shopify session manually. I do this by first retrieving the last stored token in my Shop database (connected to the current domain). I then pass that token into a new session, and activate it.

```
@mazer_shop = Shop.find_by(shopify_domain: "mazer-3.myshopify.com")
extra = { "scope" => ShopifyApp.configuration.scope.split(", ") }
@shopify_session = ShopifyAPI::Session.new(@mazer_shop.shopify_domain, @mazer_shop.shopify_token, extra)
ShopifyAPI::Base.activate_session(@shopify_session)
```

Last month (after the upgrade),  for 29 days it activated fine and did it's work without problems. However, starting on the 30th around 11AM, it began to give this error response (the second attempt that day):

```
I, [2019-03-30T08:57:18.949278 #30482]  INFO -- : GET https://mazer-3.myshopify.com:443/admin/shop.json
I, [2019-03-30T08:57:18.949392 #30482]  INFO -- : --> 200 OK 1482 (191.1ms)
I, [2019-03-30T08:57:18.949546 #30482]  INFO -- : Headers: {"Accept"=>"application/json", "User-Agent"=>"ShopifyAPI/5.2.4 ActiveResource/5.1.0 Ruby/2.4.5", "X-Shopify-Access-Token"=>"XXXXXXOmittedHereXXXXXXX"}
I, [2019-03-30T08:57:18.949581 #30482]  INFO -- : Response:
{"shop":{"id":5302909,"name":"Mazer Appliance","email":"mazer@mazer.com","domain":"mazer.com","province":"Alabama","country":"US","address1":"2  41st Street South","zip":"35222","city":"Birmingham","source":"zeekee","phone":"2052249600","latitude":33.5260509,"longitude":-86.7758489,"primary_locale":"en","address2":"","created_at":"2014-06-08T10:59:04-05:00","updated_at":"2018-12-31T11:28:19-06:00","country_code":"US","country_name":"United States","currency":"USD","customer_email":"mazer@mazer.com","timezone":"(GMT-06:00) Central Time (US \u0026 Canada)","iana_timezone":"America\/Chicago","shop_owner":"Mike Mazer","money_format":"$ {{amount}}","money_with_currency_format":"$ {{amount}} USD","weight_unit":"lb","province_code":"AL","taxes_included":false,"tax_shipping":null,"county_taxes":true,"plan_display_name":"Shopify Plus","plan_name":"shopify_plus","has_discounts":true,"has_gift_cards":true,"myshopify_domain":"mazer-3.myshopify.com","google_apps_domain":null,"google_apps_login_enabled":null,"money_in_emails_format":"${{amount}}","money_with_currency_in_emails_format":"${{amount}} USD","eligible_for_payments":true,"requires_extra_payments_agreement":false,"password_enabled":false,"has_storefront":true,"eligible_for_card_reader_giveaway":false,"finances":true,"primary_location_id":41435139,"checkout_api_supported":true,"multi_location_enabled":true,"setup_required":false,"force_ssl":true,"pre_launch_enabled":false,"enabled_presentment_currencies":["USD"]}}
E, [2019-03-30T11:00:07.254947 #30482] ERROR -- : GET https://mazer-3.myshopify.com:443/admin/shop.json
E, [2019-03-30T11:00:07.255065 #30482] ERROR -- : --> 401 Unauthorized 89 (105.2ms)
I, [2019-03-30T11:00:07.255252 #30482]  INFO -- : Headers: {"Accept"=>"application/json", "User-Agent"=>"ShopifyAPI/5.2.4 ActiveResource/5.1.0 Ruby/2.4.5", "X-Shopify-Access-Token"=>"XXXXXXOmittedHereXXXXXXX"}
I, [2019-03-30T11:00:07.255305 #30482]  INFO -- : Response: {"errors":"[API] Invalid API key or access token (unrecognized login or wrong password)"}
```

The strange thing is that the first response (which ran at 8:57AM), which started the session successfully, is using the same token as the second response, which gave the invalid API key or access token response about 2 hours later. I am guessing the token expired. However, I need a way to run a background job regardless of whether or not someone has recently logged into the app and regenerated the token. I never had this problem until after upgrading. Does any one know a way?

Comment: Interesting pattern you use. I always save the token and use it over and over again. I never have expired tokens to worry about that way, other than when a client might uninstall the App and I still have an API job going. And I never send scope into a session constructor. Why would you do that in this case? I guess you're run jobs on restricted use cases?

Comment: I actually did not send scope in the past. I made that change in a desperate attempt to mimic what I saw in the documentation when this problem started arising, thinking something changed in "Session.new".

Comment: What do you mean by "saving the token". Can you give a quick code example? I assumed that only tokens get saved when a user literally logs in, being set in the Shop session repository, and that all you could do was retrieve the last token created by that login to activate a new session with it. Are you somehow "saving" the token in your background job?

Comment: I save the token in the DB along with the shop name? How else do you do it? As long as a shop has a row in the DB, it also has a token. So when Shopify sends you a request with a shop=xxx.myshopify.com you simply look it up, and when you find it, you get the token that was issued when the App installed. I would never deal with tokens for each session, that is crazy, but ya... could be done I guess.

Comment: Help me out here, you may be on to my problem. I am looking up the shop token with this line:
`@mazer_shop = Shop.find_by(shopify_domain: "mazer-3.myshopify.com")`
Then instantiating a new session with this line:
`@shopify_session = ShopifyAPI::Session.new(@mazer_shop.shopify_domain, @mazer_shop.shopify_token, extra)`
Do I not need to instantiate a new session? Is there a way to retrieve the session itself?

Comment: Here is my background job code that never seems to fail... 

    def perform(shop_domain:, order:)
        return unless webhook_not_processed_yet?(shop_domain, order)
        shop = Shop.find_by(shopify_domain: shop_domain)
        shop.with_shopify_session do
           logger.info "Shop: #{shop_domain}"
           logger.info "Webhook Order Paid: #{order['id']}, #{order['name']}"
      
        end
      end

Comment: So yes... I am using a Rails helper there.. but it does much the same thing... as manually creating a session, so nothing extra helpful going on.